# Is having PHP handle all HTTP requests bad for performance?

Tags: php, apache

What is the resource consumption for all HTTP requests being processed by a single PHP file vs the normal setup where Apache just serves up the asset (in the case of images, for example).

The PHP file would only be making one decision.  Is the asset located here? If not then serve up the default asset.  So it is really only running file_exists for each HTTP request.

I suppose I don't understand what exactly happens each time PHP needs to do some processing.  Is the server just processing that bit of code each time?  Or is the server firing up a whole bunch of processes anytime PHP is needed vs. just serving up an image normally.

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but you can tell apache to only redirect requests for non existing files to php (using RewriteCond)

Comment: Which HTTP server are we talking about? It matters because even Apache evolved and has some nice configuration available in 2.4 which is missing in 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since you're executing a script, it's certainly not as performant as using some methods built into Apache, for example `ModRewrite`.

You could easily redirect anything that **doesn't** exist using the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule (.*) my-script.php
```

Apache will thus serve up the relevant asset if it exists at the requested URI, or will redirect the user / browser / source to `my-script.php` if it doesn't.

Comment: This is an interesting take.  Basically I need to have a default asset base (images) and several domains pointed to the same server and it needs to decide between serving up the default asset or (if it exists) serve up the one for that site. 

I think I can work with this start to get the RewriteRule to be specific for each site.